# Indexing/reshaping matrix in Python to match target matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing

I have a NumPy array that looks like the following:

```python
>>> import numpy

>>> foo = numpy.array(
    [[ 1.    ,  0.3491,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       1.    ,  0.1648,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
     [ 0.4269,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.225 ,  0.1637,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.4269,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.2929,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.4078,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
     [ 0.4212,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.1719,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.3856,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.147 ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.2459,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
     [ 0.3581,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.1676,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.2545,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.0619,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.2195,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
     [ 0.3558,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.1658,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.2544,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
       0.2159,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ]])
```

I would like to re-index and re-shape it so that it becomes the following:

```python
>>> bar
array(
[[ 1.    ,  1.    ,  1.    ,  1.    ,  1.    ],
 [ 0.4269,  0.225 ,  0.4269,  0.2929,  0.4078],
 [ 0.4212,  0.1719,  0.3856,  0.147 ,  0.2459],
 [ 0.3581,  0.1676,  0.2545,  0.0619,  0.2195],
 [ 0.3558,  0.1658,  0.2544,  0.    ,  0.2159],
 [ 0.3491,  0.1648,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
 [ 0.    ,  0.1637,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ]])
```

Is there an efficient way to do this WITHOUT using for-loops? Perhaps using [broadcasting or strides](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)?

Comment: Do you think anybody can possible copy and paste the data you have posted? Post the `repr()` output of the array similar to your expected output.

Comment: Thank you for formatting it @bignose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the array in Fortran order (or use a combination of transpositions) and then [slice](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#other-indexing-options) the array to extract only the top 7 rows:

```
a.reshape(50, -1, order='F')[:7,:]
```

The new shape chosen here was based on the location of the ones in your array. This becomes clear when you flatten the array, Fortran order, and then you see your pattern appearing.

Comment: Thank you! This worked really well. This answer makes the most sense since I'm actually trying to replicate results in R (which is based on Fortran) by wrapping a C function in Python. Weird things happened as you can see...

Answer (score 1):

First, create a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.asarray(a)

arr

array([[ 1.    ,  0.3491,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.1648,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.4269,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.225 ,  0.1637,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.4269,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.2929,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.4078,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.4212,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.1719,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.3856,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.147 ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.2459,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.3581,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.1676,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.2545,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.0619,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.2195,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.3558,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.1658,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.2544,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.2159,  0.    ,
     0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ]])
```

then, slice it with:

`b = arr[:,0:50:10]`

```
Out[13]: array([[ 1.    ,  1.    ,  1.    ,  1.    ,  1.    ],
   [ 0.4269,  0.225 ,  0.4269,  0.2929,  0.4078],
   [ 0.4212,  0.1719,  0.3856,  0.147 ,  0.2459],
   [ 0.3581,  0.1676,  0.2545,  0.0619,  0.2195],
   [ 0.3558,  0.1658,  0.2544,  0.    ,  0.2159]])
```

Then, stack the other data you want to keep:

```
c = arr[:,1:50:10]

np.vstack((b,c))
Out[17]: 
array([[ 1.    ,  1.    ,  1.    ,  1.    ,  1.    ],
   [ 0.4269,  0.225 ,  0.4269,  0.2929,  0.4078],
   [ 0.4212,  0.1719,  0.3856,  0.147 ,  0.2459],
   [ 0.3581,  0.1676,  0.2545,  0.0619,  0.2195],
   [ 0.3558,  0.1658,  0.2544,  0.    ,  0.2159],
   [ 0.3491,  0.1648,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.    ,  0.1637,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ]])
```

and with more slicing get rid of the last lines.